# R. Handling dates and wide format from an imported Stata file

Tags: r, date, import, dataframe, stata

I have been given a Stata data file (counts.dta) that contains daily counts for the years 1975 to 2006 stored in wide-format. The columns are labelled month (full name of the month as a character string), day (numeric with values 1-31), and then the years from 1975 to 2006 with labels '_1975', '_1976' ... '_2006'. I assume that the underline is a consequence of something in Stata. There are dummy counts of zero (0) inserted for the date 29 February when the year-column is not a leap year.

I want to do several things. First, convert to long form with a sensible representation for year. Second, change the tri-partite representation of the date to something more sensible.

My approach has been to change the character string month to a factor and then to get it into the correct order:

```
require("foreign")

counts <- read.dta(file='counts.dta')
counts[['month']] <- as.factor( counts[['month']] )
counts[['month']] <- 
  factor(counts[['month']], levels( counts[['month']] )[c(5,4,8,1,9,7,6,2,12,11,10,3)])
```

I then have

```
str( counts )

'data.frame':   366 obs. of  34 variables:
 $ month: Factor w/ 12 levels "January","February",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ _1975: int  515 649 745 599 445 667 725 749 646 740 ...
 $ _1976: int  485 685 529 467 630 723 712 685 715 504 ...
 $ _1977: int  505 437 489 588 634 734 682 537 453 673 ...
```

and so forth. Converting to long format

```
lcounts <- reshape(counts,
  direction="long", 
  varying=list(names( counts )[3:34]), 
  v.names="n.counts", 
  idvar=c("month","day"), 
  timevar="Year", 
  times=1975:2006)

str( lcounts )
```

gives

```
'data.frame':   11712 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ month   : Factor w/ 12 levels "January","February",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Year    : int  1975 1975 1975 1975 1975 1975 1975 1975 1975 1975 ...
 $ n.counts: int  515 649 745 599 445 667 725 749 646 740 ...
```

plus some further lines relating to the original Stata file.

My questions are: (1) what is now a good way to convert to factor-month, numeric-year and numeric-day to a useful date format, so that I can determine, for example, the day of the week, the interval between two dates and so on? (2) Was there a better way to have tackled the problem from the start?

Comment: @ExperimenteR The OP already has the data loaded in R. That advice does not help solve the actual questions being asked.

Comment: @Thomas I support comments such as those by ExperimeteR  that might be helpful in nearby territory, namely for problems very similar but not quite identical to that posted. Naturally, there is still a judgment call on where to draw the line, but the OP did ask under their (2) for broader comment, which seems legitimate given a main question giving specific detail.

Answer (score 2):

This should be pretty easy because all you have to do is paste together the rows of your data.frame and use `as.Date` to create a Date class vector.

Let's start with some data similar to yours:

```
dat <- data.frame(month = c(rep("January",31), rep("February",29)),
                  day = c(1:31, 1:29),
                  Year = 1975,
                  n.counts = 515)
```

Then the creation of the date variable is simple:

```
dat$Date <- as.Date(with(dat, paste(as.numeric(month), day, Year)), "%m %d %Y")
str(dat)
# 'data.frame':   60 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ month   : Factor w/ 2 levels "February","January": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#  $ day     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ Year    : num  1975 1975 1975 1975 1975 ...
#  $ n.counts: num  515 515 515 515 515 515 515 515 515 515 ...
#  $ Date    : Date, format: "1975-02-01" "1975-02-02" "1975-02-03" "1975-02-04" # ...
```

Comment: I see; in other words, create a completely new date structure to use together with my prior knowledge of the structure of the existing data. Very nice.

Comment: Having said 'nice', it actually turns out, I think, to be awkward. One needs to construct 366 repetitions of each of the years from 1975 to 2006 as well as doing something similar for the days of each month and the month names. Is there actually a method, simpler than what I put in my question, for (a) getting to the point I already achieved, and (b) converting the information about dates to a date format. I'd be very happy even with leaving the initial part as I have it, and finding a simple way of converting the date information to a date structure.

Comment: @user02814 The only line in the above you need to run is `as.Date(...)` the other stuff is simply to provide a data structure similar to yours to show the method. The advantage of having data in long format (as you already have it) is that you can create a date-type vector in one line of code. If you keep in wide structure, it will be much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The main focus in this thread is naturally what to do in R after data import, but here I bundle together various details on the Stata side of this.

It is longstanding advice that data of this kind are much more easily handled in Stata in a long shape and `reshape long` is a standard command to do that conversion for data arriving with each year's data in a separate variable (R users: please read "column" as a translation). So, if possible, you should ask a provider of such Stata files to do that before export.

What the OP calls labels such as `_1975` are legal variable names in Stata, and as the OP guesses the underscore is needed because variable names in Stata may not start with numeric characters.

On the information given, it would have been possible to export the data without loss from Stata in file formats other than `.dta`, notably as the usual kinds of text files (`.csv`, etc.).

Stata's preferred way of holding daily dates is as integers with origin 0 = 1 January 1960 (so 26 March 2015 would be 20173), which presumably is trivially easy to convert to any date representation in R.

In short, the particular and indeed peculiar form of the data as presented to the OP is in no sense either required by any Stata syntax or even recommended as part of good Stata practice.

Comment: One of the joys of 'open data' is not having much control over the way in which you get the data you wanted! As it turns out, the solution to my problem, in my view, is to take a piece of the suggestion from Thomas ... something I had overlooked ... and that is to use as.Date to create a new date variable within my original data frame using the variables in much the same way that Thomas suggests. But to do so, I (think) still need to convert the months to a factor so as to end up with a numeric value

Comment: Sorry. but I can't help on the R syntax you need if that's still open. My premise is that a thread should ideally have some value over and beyond any specific problem raised within it, so my remarks are pitched more generally and address only the Stata side.

Comment: I agree and certainly didn't intend to diminish the suggestion you made regarding the export from Stata. In fact, I took your comments even more generally to imply that one should practice good data-handling within whatever package you are using, and if one is moving data from one package to another, it makes sense to make use of the capabilities of the platform on the export side to simplify the whole process.